# Excel dynamic drop down using semicolon delimited data

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I have a column with cells containing more than one data element separated by the use of `;`.

Can someone help me create a VBA Macro for a drop down list with all `;` separated elements from every cell?

I've been trying to work around with some code I found, which seems to work  for single cells, but only separates elements using a comma. How can I apply this to an entire and change it for semicolons?

```
Sub List()
    Dim s As String
    s = Range("W2").Value
    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=s
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should show some own effort.

Comment: I've tried using this code, which works, but separates elements in single cells and separated by commas. Is there a way to modify this code for it to work with an entire column and with semicolons? Sorry for my complete ignorance in VBA. Thanks

Comment: Dim s As String
    s = Range("C2").Value
    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=s
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

Comment: @borsa Please don't post multi line code in comments. Line breaks in VBA matter and in comments they cannot be seen. Always put code into your original question ([edit]). Also you might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) So you should include what is wrong with your code, where exactly did you get stuck or errors. Also some example data or screenshots might help to explain your issue better.

Comment: You can't the validation list uses comma as a separator see [Data validation list entries all on one line in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/data-validation-list-entries-all-on-one-line-in-excel-4e06477d-a8d5-17e3-d643-9f84a5388e99), change your semicolons to comma.

Comment: The key to your question is in `Range("W2")` - taken from your code. According to your question it would contain several list values separated by semi-colons. if so, just change that line to `s = Replace(Range("C2").Value, ";", ",")` and your code will work. But you indicate that the range might contain several cells, each with its own list. That, if it is so, should be presented in a different question, properly explained.